# WKBackgroundRefreshTask being dealloc before its returned

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm having trouble with my WatchKit app crashing in WatchOS 5. This is happening in the background when my system calls my app to let me update the complication.

The code snippet here is called in the background when I get a WKApplicationBackgroundRefreshTask:

```
    func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        switch task {
        case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:
                HealthController().updateComplicationData {
                    self.updateComplications()
                    if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 4.0, *) {
                        backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
                    } else { task.setTaskCompleted()}
            }
```

The issue is, the crash I get basically says:

```
[WKRefreshBackgroundTask dealloc]
```

So I'm aware, this could be happening if the HealthController().updateComplicationData() function takes too long to return. But the crash doesn't imply the app is being killed for cpu time issues. It seems that the actual backgroundTask variable is getting deallocated so that when the `backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)` call happens I pass a deallocated object.

Any suggestions?

1. Could I somehow make the backgroundTask variable in a way that it doesn't get deallocated?
2. Could I be wrong about the cause of the crash and I'm missing something else?
3. Am I just forced to find a way to reduce the load that the `HealthController().updateComplicationData` creates?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may complete the task in func updatecomplicationdata()

Comment: How about use defer

Comment: So what would be the difference if I completed in the updateComplicationsData() function? as that is a synchronous bit of code I don't see why having a return from it is necessary. Not sure what a defer is

Comment: You may not know the real exec sequence after compilation. Defer guarantees after your func exec, the task termination can exec.

Comment: Ok great, can you point me anywhere for a syntax example?

Comment: defer is basic syntax in swift. You can check the swift ebook or apple samples. But in your case, have you check here ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkapplicationrefreshbackgroundtask . for details

Comment: Can you post the CrashLog here?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved this incase anyone else experiences it! Basically, I had an odd pathline of code in the background refresh where occasionally the finishedBackgroundUpdate handler wasnt called. Because of this WatchKit was killing the app. All solved now though.